# I created an installer via install4j for my app using a jar generated from maven. Why can't it find the main class when executing the .exe?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, installation, install4j

[Here's how I created a jar file using maven.](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/)

​

Now for my JavaFX Application, I'm using afterburner FX Framework. Now I need to create an installer for this app to be deployed to other devices. I'm using Install4j. My steps:

1. `mvn clean package`
2. copy and paste the generated jar file into a different directory
3. add that directory to install4j Files
4. on Launcher under Java invocation, I select the jar file, and then I select my main class: `BOOT-INF.classes.inc.pabacus.TaskMetrics.TaskMetricsApplication`
5. I Build the installer and run it, install to Program files, and then open the exe file

But then an error dialog shows up:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BOOT-INF/classes/inc/pabacus/TaskMetrics/TaskMetricsApplication (wrong name: inc/pabacus/TaskMetrics/TaskMetricsApplication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I did wrong was two things:

1. Initially, like way way back, I tried using JavaFX with Spring Framework - unsuccessfully. I'm no longer using Spring, but I still had some leftover Spring in my pom file, which caused it to put the files in a `BOOT-INF` directory when i package it to jar. I just simply had to remove the Spring leftovers, and the boot-inf directory was gone.
2. So in install4j, you select a directory that would contain the files you would add to your installer. In the tutorials, they had a separate `lib` directory which contained external libraries. So I thought that's all I needed. I copied my dependencies into a lib folder via maven, then i put them into a directory along with my jar. So that's all my directory had - the jar file and the lib folder. That doesn't work. I didn't know. Apparently, it needs ***all*** the files inside the target folder generated by maven. I should've just used the target folder itself.

So there you have it. I have now successfully created an installer. I do hope no one walks as silly as me, but if you had also encountered the same mess up, well... here ya go.

Comment: This is my first time starting a bounty, so I'm just commenting this just in case. I started the bounty before I found the answer myself.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have configured

```
BOOT-INF.classes.inc.pabacus.TaskMetrics
```

as the main class when the correct package name is

```
inc.pabacus.TaskMetrics.TaskMetricsApplication
```

Alternatively, your VM parameters configuration for the launcher is incorrect and includes text that can be interpreted main class.

Comment: Well in the install4j wizard, I was asked to select from a list of main classes. `BOOT-INF.classes.inc.pabacus.TaskMetrics` was all I had. I couldn't find any `inc.pabacus.TaskMetrics.TaskMetricsApplication`. Though I'll try later if It'll work when I just type that out.

Comment: `your VM parameters configuration for the launcher is incorrect and includes text that can be interpreted main class.` I actually didn't add any VM parameter configurations during the install4j run.

Comment: Then you have configured the class path incorrectly, if it's a directory with class files, you have to select the directory with the root package, that's the parent directory of "inc".

Comment: `you have to select the directory with the root package`
Sorry I don't quite follow. I selected whatever option showed up in the Java invocation part of the Launcher section of install4j

Comment: You can add any directory to the class path, you have to choose the correct one in terms of the class path.